# Policy has invalid resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I got an error,Policy has invalid resource .
I am using s3 of amazon,
now I do setting Bucket Policy of Permission.I wrote json in Bucket policy editor like

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ],
            "Principal":{"CanonicalUser":"64-digit-alphanumeric-value"},
        }
    ]
}
```

when I save it,Error This policy contains invalid Json error happens.I think I am wrong to write format of json,so rewrote like

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::s3.jaws-ug.tk/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

but
Error
Policy has invalid resource error happens. I really cannot understand why such a error happens.What is wrong?How should I fix this?

By reading an answer, I rewrote

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":"s3.jaws-ug.tk"
    }
  ]
}
```

but Error Policy has invalid resource error happens.

Comment: What permissions are you actually trying to grant? The two policies appear to be trying to provide different permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first policy has a number of issues:

- There is an extra comma at the end of the `Principal` line, which is causing the JSON format error
- A Bucket Policy cannot have an action of `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` because the policy is granting access for a _specific bucket`, while that command works across multiple buckets
- The `Resource` needs to point at the **specific bucket** on which the policy is applied (not *all buckets*)

The second policy is correct, but please note that the ARN must be for the bucket on which the policy is applied. So, it would work if your bucket is called `s3.jaws-ug.tk`.

Comment: I added my question.I rewrote before one into `s3.jaws-ug.tk`,but error happens.How should I fix this?

Comment: @user9929053 Your updated policy now has an invalid ARN.

Comment: Your ARN of `arn:aws:s3:::s3.jaws-ug.tk/*` is correct, as long as your bucket name is `s3.jaws-ug.tk`. What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: thank you,I could save s3 json!!By the way, when I save it,This bucket has public access
You have provided public access to this bucket. We highly recommend that you never grant any kind of public access to your S3 bucket. warning happens.Is it ok?Can I set  it private?

Comment: All objects in Amazon S3 are private by default. The policy (above) is granting public `GetObject` access for the bucket. Is that what you wanted? What access are you wanting to give the bucket?

Comment: I want to make private bucket which only members can change bucket setting and others can only access home page.Is it ok in currently bucket?

Comment: Your statement is quite confusing and is different to your original question. I suggest that you create a New Question and provide as much detail of what you wish to do. For example, include information about what you mean by "members" and "change bucket settings", and what you mean by "only access home page". Those aren't standard terms used in AWS, so please explain as much as you can in the new question so that you'll receive an appropriate Answer.